# Recursion and While Loops in Java

Tags: java, recursion, while-loop, linked-list, boolean

I'm writing a recursive program:

`public static List<Integer> method(int n)`

to determine whether a positive number `n` is the total of cubes that are positive (> 0). Example: given `n = 1944` (12^3 + 6^3), the program would return the list `[12, 6]` in descending order. If `n` is not the total of cubes the program should return an empty list.

The program should return the values that start with the highest possible value for the first element, and then follow the same rule for the rest of the elements. For example, when `n = 1072`, the program would return `[10, 4, 2]` instead of `[9, 7]`.

The method where the recursion should occur:

`private static boolean method(int n, int c, LinkedList<Integer> seen)`

where `c` is the highest number that is still allowed to be used and `soFar` is the list of numbers that have already been seen.

My code covers the base cases and the recursion, but I'm having issues with the loop continuing. With the input, `n = 1944` my program is returning the list `[12]` instead of `[12, 6]`.

```
    public static List<Integer> method(int n)
    {
        LinkedList<Integer> result = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        int c = (int) Math.cbrt(n);
        result.add(c);
        method(n, c, result);
        return result;
    }
    private static boolean method(int n, int c, LinkedList<Integer> seen)
    {
        LinkedList<Integer> result = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        boolean b = false;
        if (n == 0)
        {
          return true;  
        }
        else if (c == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else 
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i : seen)
            {
                sum += i*i*i;
            }
            while (b = false)
            {
                c = (int) Math.cbrt(n - sum);
                seen.add(c);
                method(n, c, seen);
                if (sum == n)
                {
                    result = seen;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: `j^3` isn't j-cubed, it's `j` bitwise-exclusive-OR `3`.

Comment: Elliot, 10^3 + 4^3 + 2^3 = 1072

Comment: Please stop deleting and reposting your question. This is not allowed on SO. If you don't get answers, consider improving it and/or set a bounty to the question.

Comment: sorry, don't know how to set a bounty or what that means. also I just figured that people didn't see the question and that's why. not receiving much feedback, thanks

Comment: This is because your question is very difficult to understand. In your explanation, you state that a number is equal to 12 cubed + 6 cubed, and the return value should be the list [11, 2] Why 11, instead of 12? It was things like this that made me pass it up every time I saw it before.

Comment: oh boy, i'm so sorry for that typo, I didn't realize. thanks for pointing it out, I updated the code :)

Comment: I do not see recursion in the code. If seen is defined as `LinkedList<Integer> seen` how can `seen < n` ?  Also you can not modify a collection while iterating over it using `for (int i : seen)`. Fix `j^3` as advised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see your while loop:

```java
LinkedList<Integer> result = new LinkedList<Integer>();
boolean b = false;
// Some code omitted here.
while (b = false)
{
    c = (int) Math.cbrt(n - sum);
    seen.add(c);
    method(n, c, seen);
    if (sum == n)
    {
        result = seen;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

First, with a `while` loop that always has `false` as the condition for looping, it doesn't do anything at all.

Anyway, even if we pretend the loop runs, whatever is the branch took by the `if`, a `return` will be reached. So, your `while` loop doesn't loop at all even if its condition was changed to always be `true`. Further, the only value ever assigned for the `b` variable is `false`, and it isn't used for anything at all.

Also, the `result` list in the second method is always empty. And, since the `result = seen;` instruction is just right before the `return`, it is an innocuous instruction which renders the `result` simply being useless.

Also, look at the `method(n, c, seen);` call. It don't do anything with its return value! So, even if it eventually returns `true`, you still proceeds, which would then generate `false` as a result.

Also, whenever you add a value to `seen`, it will never be removed. Since the `seen` is always the very same list in every of the recursive method calls, once  a bad number is added there, it will never be removed to make the way for something else.

With this, I must conclude that your algorithm is so broken that it must be rewritten from scratch.

Also, although your question isn't very clear, I presume that the numbers found must all be different. Otherwise, one could make `2 = 13 + 13` and every number larger than one could be represented by the sum of a lot of cubed ones (i.e. `n = 13 + 13 + 13 + ...`).

The algorithm is this:

- The first step is to have a `for` counting `i` down from `cbrt(n)` to 1 trying to form cubes.
- Then, subtract the cube from `n` and recursively try to find a cube sum for the resulting number.
- Add a parameter to avoid repeating numbers, which is one smaller than the last number used.
- When a cube is formed, return the number that formed it. In the outer calls, add the result to the list of non-empty inner recursive call.
- If an inner recursive call gives an empty list as a result, then the current iteration of the `for` produced a bad number and we should try the next one (if we have a next one).
- If the `for` ends without a cube forming, return an empty list.

Here is the code:

```java
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static List<Integer> findCubeSum(int n) {
        return findCubeSum(n, n);
    }

    public static List<Integer> findCubeSum(int n, int max) {
        if (n <= 0) return List.of();
        int c = (int) Math.cbrt(n);
        for (int i = Math.min(c, max); i > 0; i--) {
            int x = i * i * i;
            if (x == n) {
                List<Integer> result = new LinkedList<>();
                result.add(i);
                return result;
            }
            List<Integer> result = findCubeSum(n - x, i - 1);
            if (result.isEmpty()) continue;
            result.add(0, i);
            return result;
        }
        return List.of();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(findCubeSum(8));    // [2]
        System.out.println(findCubeSum(64));   // [4]
        System.out.println(findCubeSum(1000)); // [10]
        System.out.println(findCubeSum(1072)); // [10, 4, 2]
        System.out.println(findCubeSum(1944)); // [12, 6]
        System.out.println(findCubeSum(4));    // []
        System.out.println(findCubeSum(0));    // []
        System.out.println(findCubeSum(-1));   // []
        System.out.println(findCubeSum(10));   // []
    }
}
```

See it running at [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/4pnSgP).

Comment: the program has to compute all different numbers, you're correct. and it when given for example n = 1000, it can't just return the cubed root (10), it needs to find numbers the total n. It also needs to maintain the method declarations.

Comment: @Roozilla So it must be at least two different numbers even if `n` is a perfect cube itself?

Answer (score 0):

The code as posted has many issues. However your question is about `public static List<Integer> method(int n)`:

```
public static List<Integer> method(int n)  {
    LinkedList<Integer> seen = new LinkedList<>();
    method(n, 0, seen);
    return seen;
}
```

Consider changing

`private static boolean method(int n, int c, LinkedList<Integer> seen)`

To

`private static boolean method(int n, LinkedList<Integer> seen)`

because you recalculate the value of `c` by `c = (int) Math.cbrt(n);`